# Is it possible to dynamically name attributes in an App Engine Model?

Tags: google-app-engine, dynamic, setattribute, setattr, listproperty

`setattr` allows you to dynamically name attributes in Python classes. I'm trying to do something similar with an App Engine Model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Doesn't fully work
        setatr(self, 'prop1', db.ListProperty(db.Key))
        setatr(self, 'prop2', db.StringListProperty())

    # Works fully
    # prop1 = db.ListProperty(db.Key))
    # prop2 = db.StringListProperty())
```

This code compiles, but when I call `model.prop1.append(key)` later on, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ListProperty' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I suspect this is because `prop1` is declared in models instead of `self.prop1`, but I don't fully understand the syntax's significance.

Has anyone accomplished this, or does anyone have any insight into syntactic differences?

Comment: Do you actually need a dynamically added property class, or is an expando with setattr what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO question:

- [Adding a user supplied property (at runtime) to an instance of Expando class in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746942/adding-a-user-supplied-property-at-runtime-to-an-instance-of-expando-class-in-g)

gives an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the [`db.Expando`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) class (instead of `db.Model`).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but would this work maybe:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):        
        setattr(cls, 'props1', db.ListProperty(db.Key))
        setattr(cls, 'props2', db.StringListProperty())
        mymodel = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        delattr(cls, 'props1')
        delattr(cls, 'props2')
        return mymodel
```